# What is the easiest way to execute an SQLJ file?

Tags: oracle, jbuilder, ibm-data-studio, sqlj

How to run this file?

SQLJ-file :

```
import java.sql.*;
import sqlj.runtime.ref.*;

public class tes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException 
       {
         Oracle.connect
            ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@oow11:5521:sol2", "scott", "tiger");

         #sql { insert into emp (ename, empno, sal)
            values ('SALMAN', 32, 20000) };
         MyIter iter;

         #sql iter={ select ename, empno, sal from emp };
         while (iter.next()) {
            System.out.println
               (iter.ename()+" "+iter.empno()+" "+iter.sal());
         }
      }
}
```

I try to run it with jBuilder and IBM Data Studio but execution failed

[IBM data studio picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdeyl.png) 
[jBuilder picture execution fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cUlH.png)

Comment: In what way did "execution failed"? Please describe what happened, including any error messages you got.

Comment: In IBM Data Studio 

I create a javaproject  then i create a new SQLJ file.
and i added  two jar files : 
db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar
when i click run as a java application i get this error :

Selection does not cotain a main type

Comment: take a look at this
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdeyl.png

Comment: and this http://i.stack.imgur.com/7cUlH.png